# nested folder structure from path

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i want to create folder structure from path and I'am able to achieve this but it's not like that which i wanted

and path looks like this

> /docs/quick-start/messaging/Virtual-Numbers/digital/

so do you guys have any idea how can modify below code and i have removed some part of code which is not useful in this post

```
 export function useSideNavState() {
const data = useStaticQuery(SideNavQuery)
  const tree = {}

  //Working Code
  newGroups.forEach(({ name: topNodeName, nodes }) => {
    let currentNode = tree

    nodes.forEach(({ fields }) => {
      const { slug, nodeName } = fields
      // /docs/quick-start/messaging/Virtual-Numbers/digital/
      let parts = slug.split('/')
      parts = parts.filter((element) => {
        return element !== ''
      })
      const lastPart = parts[parts.length - 2]

      parts.forEach((part, index) => {
        if (part === '') return
        currentNode[part] = currentNode[part] ?? {}
        currentNode[part].name = currentNode[part].name ?? part
        currentNode = currentNode[part]
        if (index === parts.length - 2) {
          currentNode.name = nodeName ?? lastPart
        }
      })

      if (!currentNode.items) currentNode.items = []
      currentNode.items.push(fields)
      currentNode = tree
    })

    if (!tree[topNodeName]) tree[topNodeName] = {}
    tree[topNodeName][topNodeName] = {
      ...currentNode[topNodeName],
      name: topNodeName,
    }
    addNameProperty(tree[topNodeName])
  })

  // helper function to add name property recursively
  function addNameProperty(obj) {
    for (const key in obj) {
      if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
        obj[key].name = obj[key].name ?? key
        addNameProperty(obj[key])
      }
    }
  }

  console.log(tree)
  return newGroups
})
// console.log(navGroups)
return { navGroups }
```

}

from this code I'm getting output like this

```
{
"name": "docs",
"quick-start": {
    "name": "quick-start",
    "messaging": {
        "name": "messaging",
        "items": [
            {
                "title": "Messaging",
                "pageType": "doc",
                "section": "messaging",
                "order": 1,
                "slug": "/docs/quick-start/messaging/"
            }
        ],
        "Virtual-Numbers": {
            "name": "Virtual-Numbers",
            "digital": {
                "name": "digital",
                "items": [
                    {
                        "title": "digital",
                        "pageType": "doc",
                        "section": "messaging",
                        "order": -9999,
                        "slug": "/docs/quick-start/messaging/Virtual-Numbers/digital/"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "items": [
                {
                    "title": "EnableX Virtual Numbers",
                    "pageType": "doc",
                    "section": "messaging",
                    "order": -9999,
                    "slug": "/docs/quick-start/messaging/Virtual-Numbers"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

}

but i wanted something like this without key name

```
{
"name": "docs",
 {
    "name": "quick-start",
    {
        "name": "messaging",
        "items": [
            {
                "title": "Messaging",
                "pageType": "doc",
                "section": "messaging",
                "order": 1,
                "slug": "/docs/quick-start/messaging/"
            }
        ],
         {
            "name": "Virtual-Numbers",
            {
                "name": "digital",
                "items": [
                    {
                        "title": "digital",
                        "pageType": "doc",
                        "section": "messaging",
                        "order": -9999,
                        "slug": "/docs/quick-start/messaging/Virtual-Numbers/digital/"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "items": [
                {
                    "title": "EnableX Virtual Numbers",
                    "pageType": "doc",
                    "section": "messaging",
                    "order": -9999,
                    "slug": "/docs/quick-start/messaging/Virtual-Numbers"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Without key name, it is not a valid JSON. Why without keys? Need arrays?

Comment: without keys because data is dynamic so whenever i change category the key name changes so it show undefined or null .. yes arrays will work fine can you give any idea how can i achieve this